# make command doesn't produce any executable

Tags: make, gcc

My `Makefile` contains the following:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall

main: hello.o hello_fn.o

clean:
   rm -f main hello.o hello_fn.o
```

It should have produced an executable file `main` (I've read that in Introduction to GCC by Brian Gough), but actually it haven't.

The output should be like this:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -c -o hello.o main.c
gcc -Wall -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
gcc hello.o hello_fn.o -o main
```

But actually it's like this:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -Wall   -c -o hello_fn.o hello_fn.c
```

When I type `$ make` again, it says that `'main' is up to date`.

Files in the current directory:

```
$ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 rodion rodion 4096 Oct  4 15:39 ./
drwxr-x--- 13 rodion rodion 4096 Oct  4 15:39 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 rodion rodion  104 Oct  4 00:29 hello_fn.c
-rw-r--r--  1 rodion rodion   31 Oct  4 00:21 hello.h
-rw-r--r--  1 rodion rodion   84 Oct  4 00:28 main.c
-rw-r--r--  1 rodion rodion   84 Oct  4 12:18 Makefile
```

`make` version:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Contents of all files:

```
$ cat hello.c

#include "stdio.h"
#include "hello.h"

int main ()
{
   hello ("world");
   return 0;
}
```

```
$ cat hello_fn.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void hello (const char * name)
{
   printf ("Hello %s\n", name);
}
```

```
$ cat hello.h

void hello(const char * name);
```

Comment: You didn't set the linker (as variable name). I recommend not to use implicit rules (they are not so much portable). BTW what is the output of `make -v`? Which distribution are you using?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi implicit rules are defined by POSIX...

Comment: @StephenKitt: I do not find the explicit rule to create a binary from a .o file (and I think it is the problem here). But my point: if I need to look POSIX documentation every time to see what it is automatically implemented, we are losing time. A general tule: Explicit is better then implicit.

Comment: That rule is about *.c into a binary. But this problem is different. We use implicit .c.o, and it is working (as in the question). So now we need a rule which convert .o into binary, which I still do not find in it.

Comment: @StephenKitt: see previous comment. Note: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html seems to correctly interpret `x: y.o z.o` which it is this case. So I'm still confused why it doesn't work in GNU make.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it doesn’t work because there has to be a file matching the name of the executable: `x: y.o z.o` implies `x: x.o y.o z.o` (“one of which has a name matching that of the executable file” in the description of the rule in the manual). That’s not the case here.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi and yes, sorry, you’re right about the POSIX rules, that one is just for single-file binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you’re referring to [this document](https://github.com/briangough/gccintro), the first `Makefile` isn’t quite the same as in your question:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

main: main.o hello_fn.o

clean:
    rm -f main main.o hello_fn.o
```

`main` has **`main.o`** and `hello_fn.o` as prerequisites, not `hello.o`. Fixing that produces a working `Makefile`.

This relies on a [built-in rule in GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html), of the form

```
x: y.o z.o
```

which expects **`x.c`** to exist (and `y.o` and `z.o` to be buildable). So the name of your binary target has to match a `.c` file in the current directory.

Comment: Yes, I also thought like that. I changed all `hello` to `main`. Didn't work anyway though.

Comment: I've edited my post and stated the contents off all files.

Comment: You need a `main.c` file, see section 2.5 in the document. Your `ll` output says you have one...

Comment: check out that image, please: https://imgur.com/a/AG1jTC7 . I've managed to produce executable! I'm curious where the problem is...

Comment: Take a look at that image, please: https://imgur.com/a/zjvuRsv . All I did is just created the same files again in another directory (The new files are in the right terminal; I wrote their contents again by hand). Files' contents are the same as before. And, lo and behold, everything works for the newly created files. Magic?

Comment: That’s very strange! I’m assuming your `vim` on the left was to fix the `#include <stdio.h>` line and nothing else. From `test1`, does `diff -ur . ..|grep -v "Only in"` show anything?

Comment: This is ridiculous. I found that was wrong. Here's the image: https://imgur.com/a/9TfOuta . To the left is the old `Makefile` and to the right is the new `Makefile`. The TAB symbol in the old `Makefile` was preventing the `make` command from generating an executable.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it — the tab tells `make` that it should run no command to build `main` :-/. Emacs highlights misplaced tabs to avoid this, there might be a way to do that in Vim too.